# accent menu and not operational key repeat not working macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: key, repeat

I need the different characters and vowels for coding and localization.
Tried the command with boolean true 
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
It did not work.

Could you help fix the issue, please? Thank you.

Comment: I have the opposite problem!  Most keys *don't* repeat in most apps, but instead show an accented character menu.  Ugh (for me)!

Comment: Do you have some antivirus like WebRoot? Because the "keyword protected mode" may disable the accent menu.

Answer (score 1):

I used `defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` to *suppress* the accent menu, so you could try the opposite: `defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` and then restart the app in question (command-q from the app and then restart it).